# How to get the group member list from a Linux computer in the domain? Samba AD/DC

Tags: linux, samba, groups

If I run the following command in the computer running as Samba AD/DC i have no issues. It works.
`sudo samba-tool group listmembers 'domain users'`

The problem is I would like to read the same (and other groups) list of users from another Linux computer in the domain. I am logged in as Domain user in Linux, installed PAM winbind.

I tried `wbinfo`, it works, but I could not get the group member list with that. `getent` gives me groups and users of the domain. But still I can't find the proper way to list the group memebers.

Any suggestion?

Comment: I can of course `ssh` do the DC and run the `samba-tool` command, but i was looking for something to be run without `sudo`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to use ldapsearch instead of smb-tools. Something to the effect of;

```
ldapsearch -LLL -b "dc=example,dc=com" "(&(cn=*)(memberUid=user))" dn
```

Answer (score 1):

You are so very nearly there, your command is just missing a vital piece of information. You need to add '-H ldap://samdom.example.com' to the command, where 'samdom.example.com' is your dns domain.

Answer (score 1):

Thank to @CryptoJones I watched into LDAP. Here is what I did to have it working.

First of all, the two computers I am using in this example are both Debian 10. Samba and all other software was installed as a Debian package. Samba AD/DC configuration followed the example in the official Samba website.

My AD/DC create the domain "windom.borghi.lan" and its name is "dc1.windom.borghi.lan". I call AD from the machine "linte.windom.borghi.lan", where I am logged in as Domain user "WINDOM\nicola".

In the machine "linte" I installed two packages:

```
$> sudo apt-get install libsasl2-modules-gssapi-mit
$> sudo apt-get install libsasl2-modules-gssapi-heimdal
```

Then, to query all the members of my Domain group 'g-leggiTutto' I do:

```
linte WINDOM\nicola> ldapsearch  -H ldap://dc1 -Y GSSAPI -b "dc=windom,dc=borghi,dc=lan" '(memberOf=CN=g-leggitutto*)'
```

AFAICsay it is not possible to use the previous method to look for all the users of the group "Domain Users". But, you can search all the users and then filter them. It is the first time I use LDAP, there might be better ways.

```
linte WINDOM\nicola> ldapsearch  -H ldap://dc1 -Y GSSAPI -b "dc=windom,dc=borghi,dc=lan" '(sAMAccountName=*)'
```

Then I filter out group entries and computer entries and I get a reasonable result.

```
linte WINDOM\nicola> ldapsearch  -H ldap://dc1 -Y GSSAPI -b "dc=windom,dc=borghi,dc=lan" '(&(sAMAccountName=*)(!(objectClass=group))(!(objectClass=computer)) )'
```

bye

Comment: No, you cannot search for all members of the Domain Users group by the 'memberOf' attribute, because all users are members of Domain Users and do not have that attribute. The primaryGroupID is used instead for Domain Users. I prefer my way, it works without the filtering, I would also suggest you use ldbsearch instead of ldapsearch, it is more secure. I suppose that I should point out that you only need one of the ;libsasl2-*' packages, the one ending in 'heimdal'. Can I also suggest that, if you have any further questions to do with Samba AD, you ask them on the samba mailing list

Comment: I took a look at primaryGroupID. That seems to be the best solution to list Domain Users. To be explicit: `"(primaryGroupId=513)"` .

Comment: To be exact: (&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(primaryGroupID=513)) , though you will get the same output from 'wbinfo -u' and 'samba-tool user list'